# NSFetchedResultsController not recognizing deletes

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a multiple number of Core Data entities, all synced to the server. For testing I have built a function that will:
1. Delete all of the core data entities
2. Call APIs to refresh all data

```
     // Next delete data in all entities (but not user)
    for entity in CoreDataStack.sharedInstance.allEntities() {
        if (entity != "User") {
            if (DataAccess.deleteExisting(entityName: entity, inMoc: self.operationMOC)) {
                print("Deleted OK: \(entity)")
            } else {
                print("ERROR deleting \(entity)")
            }
        }
    }

    ....

    // Save updates
    self.operationMOC.performAndWait {
        do {
            try self.operationMOC.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("ERROR: Failed to save operation moc: \(error)")
        }
    }
    self.mainThreadMOC.performAndWait {
        do {
            try self.mainThreadMOC.save()
        } catch {
            fatalError("ERROR: Failed to save main moc: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the NSFetchedResultsController controlling my UI seems not to recognize the delete, giving an error when the "didChange" delegate method fires for the update

> error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (14) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

I have split the refresh function into 2 parts so I can see that the delete is never recognized, hence there are too many UITableView rows when the update fires and tries to tableView.insertRows(at: ...). 
I have also tried direct updates to the MOC on my main thread - no luck

I have also put in an observer:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MessagesTab.dataChanged), name: NSNotification.Name.NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange, object: self.mainThreadMOC)
```

Which fires perfectly on delete and update, so Core Data is doing it's job.

Consequently, my question before I dump the NSFetchResults Controller and roll my own using notifications, is does anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong here? (either in code or expectations)
I have been stumped on this for the past day so any advice would be gratefully received.

My NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate didChange method:

```
func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
    print(">>>> FRC Change Fired")
    switch type {
    case .insert:
        tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
    case .delete:
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .automatic)
    case .update:
        let rowMessage = self.fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath!)
        if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as? InterestsListCell {
            cell.configureWithData(rowMessage)
        }
    default:
        print("Was not a update, delete or insert")
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to post your fetchResultsDelegate didChangeObject method, this is where the issue lies.

Comment: @SeanLintern88, thanks for the fast response. delegate method posted, although I don't think there is much wrong with it

Comment: in your numberOfItemForSection on the tableView, do you reference FRC.fetchedObjects.count or a self stored array ?

Comment: The reason its crashing is your datasource of that tableView is not lining up with the datasource objects.

Comment: @SeanLintern88 thanks again for looking at this: 1. I think that my numberOfRowsInSection is OK: let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section], let numberOfRows = sectionInfo.numberOfObjects . 2. Please can you explain what you mean by the datasource not lining up: I am using a UITableViewController - datasource hooked up via Storyboard, and my FetchedResultsController is fetching objects on my main thread

Comment: Yeah, I just mean you need to look at what objects your deleting, making sure they are deleted from your tableview datasource, otherwise the numberOfRows wont line up, if your FRC is on a diff context then it may not be updated from the delete ?

Comment: When i say datasource, I mean your FRC.fetchedObjects, this may not get updated when you are deleting the objects in it in another place in the app if they are not on the same context, and that context is saved, which means you your FRC context is updated the number of objects in the table, the rows, when you do an update are not the correct values according to the datasource. When using FRC, try to think that the FRC.fetchedObjects and tableview are very tighlty bound, if one changes and not the other, easy crash.

Comment: @SeanLintern88 - yep, that's exactly my issue. Changes are not being recognized by the FRC, but they are by a NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange notification (both using my main MOC)

Comment: If the object is not faulted in the mainContext when the change is merged then the FRC will not fire.  You can fault them using existingObjectWithID:.

Comment: @JonRose, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I am deleting the entire table, so deleting the faulted objects should fire the FRC

Comment: Are you deleting using a BatchDeleteRequest?  Those types of changes will not trigger an FRC and for that reason I avoid using them.

Comment: @JonRose PERFECT! Yes I am, this makes perfect sense. I have been going round in circles trying to make it work, but will now revert to Notifications - thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many thanks to @JonRose
This code will NOT cause the FRC to fire

```
    // Delete all records for the entity
    func deleteExisting(entityName: String, inMoc moc: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Bool {
    do {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: entityName)
        let deleteRequest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(fetchRequest: request)
        try moc.execute(deleteRequest)
        return true
    } catch {
        print("ERROR: deleting existing records - \(entityName)")
        return false
    }
}
```

Subsequently I have researched this and hope that it will help others - see [WWDC 2015 session on Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/220/) where this slide was shown:[image]
I have tried using .refreshAll() and .mergeChages, but the simples for me seemed to be to ditch my FRC and use NSManagedObjectContextDidSave notification

Comment: Thank you!!!  I just watched this and I still missed that first line of that slide - see what I ended up doing below if you are still having this issue but want to use the FRC

Answer (score 0):

This is expected behaviour as the batch deletion/updation happens directly on Store as @redPanda pointed out. You can try refreshing the context (generally 'main' as its the context with which the FRC should be attached to) using

```
context.refreshAllObjects()
```

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for the FRC

Answer (score 0):

I ended up nil-ing out my FRC then rebuilding it after the batch delete completes

```
    fetchedResultsController = nil

    dataProvider?.deleteAllAlertsBatch  { error in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(" done delete \(error)")
            self.loadSavedData() // <- build the FRC again here - it will find 0 records

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, the `NSBatchDeleteRequest` does not reflect changes in the context. Nil-ing out the FRC could cause problems updating a `UITableView` when the new FRC is added.

`context.refreshAllObjects()` is the way to go but to add to @infinateLoop's answer (I'm unable to comment):

```swift
func deleteAndUpdate() {

    DeleteRecords(moc: context) // your NSBatchDeleteRequest function here

    context.refreshAllObjects()
    try? frc.performFetch() // catch error if required
    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the other answers/comments `NSBatchDeleteRequest` are performed on a SQL level thus are not recognised by the `FetchResultsController` (RFC). To reflect deletes on the RFC one has two options:

#### 1. Sync deletes back into the context

Stick with the `NSBatchDeleteRequest` and sync back the changes like Apple describes in their [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsbatchdeleterequest).
The `NSBatchDeleteRequest` only works for SQLite persistent stores.
The `NSBatchDeleteRequest` is not compatible with any validation rule.

```swift
// create deleteRequest
let deleteReuqest = NSBatchDeleteRequest(objectIDs: toDelete.map(\.oid))

// define that the result are the deleted IDs 
deleteReuqest.resultType = .resultTypeObjectIDs

// run the BatchDelete
let deleteResult = try context.execute(deleteReuqest) as? NSBatchDeleteResult

// gather the deletedIds and sync the changes into the context
if let objectIDs = deleteResult?.result as? [NSManagedObjectID] {
    NSManagedObjectContext.mergeChanges(fromRemoteContextSave: [NSDeletedObjectsKey: objectIDs], into: [context])
}
```

#### 2. Use single deletes

If you don't have to delete a lot of objects at once it may make sense to stop using the BatchDelete completely and switch to deleting single objects. Single deletes are not on an SQL level thus immediately recognised by the RFC without any extra work.

```swift
// run this for every object you want to delete
context.delete(objectToBeDeleted)
```

#### Some help to pick one over the other

If you have a **large** number of objects to delete -> `NSBatchRequest`
If you want to rely on `validation rules` -> `context.delete(...)`